# My very first Lua code. But hey i am stuck

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Okay so here i am, a guy who is new to the Lua language.
My problem is i can´t get a code as i want it to run.

So I want my code to show 1 new image for 1 each tap.

So if i tap 3 times 3 pictures on the display will show up.

Here is my code so far and trust me i googled and googled but i couldnt find anything that could help me out so i guess this is my last solution.

```
function screenTap() 

local randomPicture = display.newImage("pictures/Boy.png")

randomPicture.x = 160;
randomPicture.y = 250;
randomPicture.width = 250;
randomPicture.height = 250;

end
display.currentStage:addEventListener("tap",screenTap)
```

This code will display a picture as i tap. (One tap will display the picture).
My problem: I want to gain one picture per tap. All picture will still be displayed on the screen. So i could have like 1000 pictures if i tapped 1000 times.

Comment: Well, what *does* happen? What's not working?

Comment: This code runs fine, but if i would add another picture to this function. 2 pictures would have shown at the same time wich is my biggest problem right now. I want my code to show 1 picture for each tap.

Comment: Please update your question with a clear description of the problem, including what actually happens vs. what you expected to happen.

Answer (score 1):

You should clean your previous image. To do this, move reference to the `picture` variable to outer scope. Then, you should keep an index of current image, so you can iterate through `pictures` array on every tap. Or you can use `math.random` to get random image index on every tap.

```
-- Keep reference to current image, needed only if you want to move or delete this picture in the future
local picture = nil

-- Array with image names, you should have 3 images with exact name in your resources
local pictures = {"Boy", "Girl", "Animal"}

-- Keep index of current image, needed to iterate through images array every tap
local pictureId = 0


-- Add `event` into arguments, so now you can receive more info from this event
function screenTap( event )

    -- If you don't need to clear previous image, remove this lines
    if picture ~= nil then 
        picture:removeSelf()
        picture = nil
    end

    -- Avery call of this function create a new image with current picture index
    picture = display.newImage("pictures/" .. pictures[idx] .. ".png")

    -- Use `event` to get point where user tap, and move image on that position
    picture.x = event.x
    picture.y = event.y
    picture.width = 250
    picture.height = 250

    -- Increment index of the current picture
    pictureId += 1

    -- If it is greater then or equal number of pictures — reset it to zero
    if pictureId >= #pictures then
        pictureId = 0
    end

end

display.currentStage:addEventListener("tap", screenTap)
```

Comment: This is not what i am looking for. It is very simple to explain. If i tap one time i will get 1 picture. if i tap again i will then get another picture.

Comment: If you want to place pictures on the same place that you have been tapped, you should add `event` into your function arguments, and then use `event.x` and `event.y` instead of hardcoded values.

Comment: Okay, thank you! But could you explain this code for me step by step?

Comment: The problem is i dont understand if i should replace any code or not?

Comment: Add comments to the code. Generally, if you don't need to clear previous image and draw different images on every tap, delete everything except code related to `event` argument.